# How do I export data from filemaker?

Tags: export, filemaker

This is my first time using filemaker and I'm in the process of converting a client's filemaker project to a webapp. Currently, I am trying to export the current data so that I can put it in a database.

I've found that tables don't appear for export unless they appear in the "Relationships" graph, and I've found that I can export the data using the "Export Records" script command.

This all works fine except that I can't seem to export all the records. In the database manager, one of the tables reports that it has 596 records, but when I export it I only get 119 records. The same is true for all other tables I've tried, they report more than 119 records, but the exported data only has 119.

Any ideas or help is welcome

**edit**

More progress, it seems the script runs in the context of the current layout, so the number of records is related to the number of results in the current layout. Is there a way to automate creating layouts for tables that don't have them so that I can export all the data for each table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept you were missing was the "found set". FileMaker exports the currently found records in the current layout. You can create a script that grabs the names of the layouts within the file, sticks into a variable, goes to each layout in turn, performs a Show All Records, and then runs an open ended export. However, I'm wondering how many base tables there actually are?

As to creating layouts - nope, there's no programmatic way. However, it is possible to use an external key macro type app (QuicKeys?) to run through the create layout dialog and choose a new table each time.